# Vim - create numbered backup files?

Tags: linux, backup, vim

I find myself wanting Vim to create numbered backup files, so every time I save there's some ordinal number in the back-file name.  My current impetus is that I make changes in C code that have un-imagined catastrophic side-effects, and I'd like to diff all the "little tweaks" I made while reading through the code that caused the problem.  They might have been made a few edits ago, and only just come to light.   By then it's too late to undo.

For example, say I exit `foo.txt`, Vim creates a `foo.txt~`, but that's *not enough*.

When I re-edit (or re-save) `foo.txt`, I want it to create a backup named something like `foo.txt~001`, `foo.txt~002` ... `foo.txt~421`, etc.

Is this already possible?

(Back in former times, certain mainframe editors would do this automatically.)

I don't care if it's 1,2,3 or a timestamp, whatever.  Just some way to track the last `N` changes (where I imagine setting N to about 100 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no vim option to do this directly, but in the [vim documentation](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backupext%27) for the option `backupext` (which specifies the extension used for backup files) there is a suggestion how to perform exactly what you are asking for (albeit with timestamps instead of numbers, but you get basically the same effect):

```
    If you like to keep a lot of backups, you could use a BufWritePre
    autocommand to change 'backupext' just before writing the file to
    include a timestamp.
        :au BufWritePre * let &bex = '-' . strftime("%Y%b%d%X") . '~'
    Use 'backupdir' to put the backup in a different directory.
```

Having said that, for your use case you should really have a look at [Version Control Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), two popular ones are [git](https://git-scm.com/) and [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

Comment: This works well, and does what I need (ordered multiple backup files).  However the example above puts colons `:` into the filename, and these are only valid on some filesystems (not windows, not android).  Thus I decided on:  `au BufWritePre * let &bex = '-' . strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") . '~'`   Which gives a date+time number with seconds resolution.  It's a bit long, but is otherwise great.